Conjecture: If $n$ is an odd positive integer then $\gcd\left(2^{n}+5,5^{n}-3^{n}\right)=1$.
I've tried to prove that $2^{n}+5$ will not divide $5^{n}-3^{n}$ using Jacobi symbol , but this is still not sufficient to prove that $\gcd\left(2^{n}+5,5^{n}-3^{n}\right)=1$.
The proof of $2^{n}+5$ will not divide $5^{n}-3^{n}$ :
Assuming that $2^{n}+5$ will divide $5^{n}-3^{n}$ :
If n is even
As $\operatorname{ord}_3(2) = 2$ , so $2^{2k} \equiv 1 \pmod{3}$
and $5 \equiv -1 \pmod{3}$
Thus $ 2^{2k} +5 \equiv 0 \pmod{3}$ , so $3$ $\mid$ $2^{n}+5$ $\Rightarrow$ $ 3 \mid 5^{n}-3^{n}$ , which is a contradiction !
$\Rightarrow$ n is odd
How ever , $2^{n}+5$ will divide $5^{n}-3^{n} \Rightarrow 5^n \equiv 3^n \pmod{2^{n}+5}$
$\Rightarrow \displaystyle \left( \frac{5^n}{2^{n}+5} \right)$ $=$
$\displaystyle \left( \frac{3^n}{2^{n}+5} \right)$
$\Rightarrow \displaystyle \left( \frac{5}{2^{n}+5} \right)^n =  \displaystyle \left( \frac{3}{2^{n}+5} \right) ^n$
Since n is odd $\Rightarrow \displaystyle \left( \frac{5}{2^{n}+5} \right) =  \displaystyle \left( \frac{3}{2^{n}+5} \right)$
Now using the extended law of quadratic reciprocity with the Jacobi symbol , if a and b are odd positive coprime integers then : $
\displaystyle \left( \frac{a}{b} \right) = (-1)^{\frac{(a-1)(b-1)}{4}}$ $\displaystyle \left( \frac{b}{a} \right)$
In our case $5$ and $2^n + 5$ are odd positive coprime integers , also for $3$ and $2^n +5$.
Thus $\displaystyle \left( \frac{5}{2^{n}+5} \right) = \displaystyle \left( \frac{2^{n}+5}{5} \right) \times (-1)^{\frac{5-1}{2} \times \frac{2^{n}+5-1}{2}} = \displaystyle \left( \frac{2^{n}+5}{5} \right)$ because $\frac{5-1}{2} =2$
$\Rightarrow \displaystyle \left( \frac{2^{n}+5}{5} \right) = \displaystyle \left( \frac{2^{n}}{5} \right)$ because $\text{if } a \equiv b \pmod{c}, \text{ then } \displaystyle \left( \frac{a}{c} \right) = \left( \frac{b}{c} \right)$
$\Rightarrow  \displaystyle \left( \frac{2^{n}}{5} \right) = \displaystyle \left( \frac{2}{5} \right)^n = (-1)^{\frac{5^2-1}{8}} = (-1)^3 = -1$
In the other hand , using the extended law of quadratic reciprocity, we have :
$\displaystyle \left( \frac{3}{2^{n}+5} \right) = \displaystyle \left( \frac{2^{n}+5}{3} \right) \times (-1)^{\frac{3-1}{2} \times \frac{2^{n}+5-1}{2}} = \displaystyle \left( \frac{2^{n}+5}{3} \right) \times (-1)^{\frac{2^{n}+4}{2}}$
$= \displaystyle \left( \frac{2^{n}+5}{3} \right) \times (-1)^{2^{n-1}+2} = \displaystyle \left( \frac{2^{n}+5}{3} \right)$ , because $n > 1$
$\Rightarrow \displaystyle \left( \frac{2^{n}+5}{3} \right) = \displaystyle \left( \frac{(-1)^{n}-1}{3} \right) $ , since $5 \equiv -1 \pmod{3}$ and $2 \equiv -1 \pmod{3}$
As n is odd, then $\displaystyle \left( \frac{(-1)^{n}-1}{3} \right) = \displaystyle \left( \frac{-2}{3} \right) = \displaystyle \left( \frac{1}{3} \right) = 1$
Thus $\displaystyle \left( \frac{5^n}{2^{n}+5} \right)$ $=$
$\displaystyle \left( \frac{3^n}{2^{n}+5} \right) = 1 =-1$ which is a contradiction !
Conclusion , $2^{n}+5$ will not divide $5^{n}-3^{n}$ but why $\gcd\left(2^{n}+5,5^{n}-3^{n}\right)=1$ ?
Thanks for help !

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

A general technique would be to find integers $x_n$ and $y_n$ such that $(2^{n}+5)x_n+(5^{n}-3^{n})y_n=1$ for every $n$ odd. It seems doable to find a recursive formula (linear with constant integer coefficients) relating $(x_{n+2},y_{n+2})$ to $(x_n,y_n)$, then the result would follow by induction. Have you tried that direction?

The Bézout coefficients $(x_{n},y_{n})$ are so hard to predict , I've also got stuck in the proof by induction !

I strongly suspect this conjecture is false. For every prime $p$, the number $5\cdot 3^{-1}$ has some order $k_p$ modulo $p$; a fair amount of the time $k_p$ will be odd. The “probability” that $2^{k_p}\equiv -5\pmod p$ is presumably $1/(p-1)$. A probabilistic heuristic then suggests that there are infinitely many primes $p$ that divide both $2^{k_p}+5$ and $(5\cdot 3^{-1})^{k_p}-1$; the latter divisibility implies that $p$ also divides $5^{k_p}-3^{k_p}$.

Give me a contradiction  to believe you !

Are you aware your hypothesis does not work for $n=0$? :-)

$0$ is even not odd !

To clarify the new bounty motivation. There already is an accepted answer with the counterexample. What do you expect from a more detailed answer?

@AlexRavsky I completely agree with you, it's really strange to put bounty again even though we already have nice solution, maybe he wants reason for why his try to prove the conjecture is not correct?

@MathAdmiral In the last comment
is asked about a possibility for an analytical proof. Towards this in the comment
before that is described the counterexample idea.

Moreover, in the answer $p=\frac{5^{25}-3^{25}}{5^5-3^5}$,
so it remains to show that for $m=19\cdot 7452566419$ (or for some natural $m$), $2^{25m}+5$ is divisible by $p$.

Let $n_0$ be an odd integer such that $n_0 \geq 3$.
Since $\gcd(5, 3) = 1$, by Zsigmondy’s theorem, $5^{n_0} - 3^{n_0}$ has a primitive prime divisor $p$.

In particular, $p$ is odd (since $p$ does not divide $5 - 3$) moreover $p \neq 3$, so $3$ has an inverse modulo $p$.

In the cyclic group $(F_p^*, \times)$ where $F_p = \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, we have $\frac{5}{3}$ of order $n_0$: $O\left(\frac{5}{3}\right) = n_0$. Thus, $p \mid 5^n - 3^n$ if and only if $n_0 \mid n$.
To find $n$ such that $\gcd(5^n - 3^n, 2^n + 5) > 1$, it suffices that $n = (2k + 1)n_0$ and $p \mid 2^n + 5$.
In $(F_p^{*},\times)$:
$$2^{(2k+1)n_0} + 5 = 0 \quad \Rightarrow \quad (4^{n_0})^k = -\frac{5}{2^{n_0}} ,$$
where $2^{n_0}$ is invertible modulo $p$ (since $p$ is odd). Thus, we have $-\frac{5}{2^{n_0}} \in \text{gr}(4^{n_0})$, where $\text{gr}(4^{n_0})$ denotes the subgroup of $(F_p)^*$ generated by $4^{n_0}$.
We recall that , in a cyclic group, $x \in \text{gr}(a)$ if and only if $o(x)$ divides $o(a)$.
Thus,
$$-\frac{5}{2^{n_0}} \in \text{gr}(4^{n_0}) \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad o\left(-\frac{5}{2^{n_0}}\right) \mid o(4^{n_0}).$$
Conclusion:
To find the existence of an odd $n$ such that $\gcd(5^n - 3^n, 2^n + 5) > 1$, follow these steps:
Start with $n_0 = 3$. If a primitive divisor $p$ of $5^{n_0} - 3^{n_0}$ is found such that $o\left(-\frac{5}{2^{n_0}}\right)$ divides $o(4^{n_0})$, then we are done. Otherwise, replace $n_0$ by $n_0 + 2$ and repeat the process.
For $n_0 = 25$, we verify the factorization of $5^{n_0} - 3^{n_0}$ as:
$$5^{n_0} - 3^{n_0} = 131 \times 2 \times 11 \times p,$$
where $p = 103408180634401$.
Since $5^5 - 3^5 = 2 \times 11 \times 131$, $p$ is a primitive prime divisor of $5^{n_0} - 3^{n_0}$ and $o\left(\frac{5}{3}\right) = 25$ in $(F_p^*, \times)$.
Additionally, we have $o\left(-\frac{5}{2^{n_0}}\right) = 43086741931$, and $o(4^{n_0}) = 517040903172 = 12 \times o\left(-\frac{5}{2^{n_0}}\right)$.
Thus, there exists a $k \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $-\frac{5}{2^{n_0}} = (4^{n_0})^k$, and hence $n = n_0(2k + 1)$ answers the question.
Remark , there is infinitely odd numbers n such that $\gcd(5^n-3^n,2^n+5) \neq 1$
In fact, it suffices to replace $k$ by $k'=k+m\times(p-1)$

A quick search has revealed that when
$$n = 3539969049025$$
the numbers $2^n + 5$ and $5^n - 3^n$ have common factor
$$p = 103408180634401.$$
The python code to check this is pasted below
p = 103408180634401
n = 3539969049025

#exponential modulo p
def exp(a, n, p):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    b = exp(a, n // 2, p)
    b = (b * b) % p
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return b
    else:
        return (b * a) % p

print((exp(2, n, p) + 5) % p)
print((exp(5, n, p) - exp(3, n, p)) % p)

Or using builtin functions
p = 103408180634401
n = 3539969049025

print((pow(2, n, p) + 5) % p)
print((pow(5, n, p) - pow(3, n, p)) % p)


Nice answer! FYI, Python's builtin pow function provides the same functionality as your exp function when called with 3 inputs.

Thank you for this suggestion! I don't know about this and I will modify the code accordingly.

@abacaba Wow! How did you find these numbers? My naively implemented computer search only got up to p = 10 million or so before becoming too slow to be feasible.

your solution is excellent! I was impressed by your approach. I attempted to use Mathematica to find a counterexample and did find one at 304. However, I deleted my answer as the prompt specified odd numbers. Despite my inability to find an odd counterexample, I then tried to search for one but was unsuccessful.
It's interesting to note that the counterexample appears at a large exponent. Could you share the approximate runtime of your program? I found Mathematica to be quite slow when I used it for this task.
I highly admire your work and wish you the best of luck.

I did not search over $p$. I search over $n$ instead. The trick is that if $5^n - 3^n$ is divisible by $p$, then so is $5^{kn} - 3^{kn}$. I start from some small $n$ ($n = 25$ in the successful case), factor $5^n - 3^n$, then for each prime factor $p$ try to solve the discrete log problem $(2^{n})^k \equiv -5 \bmod{p}$, hoping that $k$ exists and is odd.

Is there a possibility for an analytical proof? considering that the exponent is so large, it's more likely (I think) to be done via a contradiction. (How else would you prove that this conjecture is false? )
